# Fetch discord users using nextjs

Tags: next.js, discord

I want to show the users on the discord server on my website with Next Js, how can I do this? I tried many ways, but I am getting an error, I have stated the error and my codes at the bottom. I have searched many places but no one does what I am trying to do.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
   6 | <h1>Discord Guild Members</h1>
   7 | <ul>
>  8 |   {members.map((member) => (
     |           ^
   9 |     <li key={member.user.id}>
  10 |       <img src={getUserAvatarURL(member.user.id, member.user.avatar)} alt="Avatar" />
  11 |       <span>{member.user.username}</span>
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Discord sunucu bilgilerinizi aşağıdaki değişkenlere girin
const guildId = 'myGuildId';
const token = 'myBotToken';

export const getGuildMembers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/${guildId}/members`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bot ${token}`,
        },
      });
  
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching guild members:', error);
      return []; 
    }
  };
  

export const getUserAvatarURL = (userId, avatarHash) => {
  if (avatarHash.startsWith('a_')) {
    return `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${userId}/${avatarHash}.gif`;
  } else {
    return `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${userId}/${avatarHash}.png`;
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't see an error?